# Android, videoView can't open this video Online video

Tags: android, android-videoview

I used videoView to play an mp4 file from the Internet, but it can't play this video all the time.
This is my code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://vfx.mtime.cn/Video/2019/02/08/mp4/190208204943376259.mp4");
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(createOnPreparedListener());

private MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener createOnPreparedListener(){
        return new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        };
    }
```

It could run well in my emulator, but not success in my android device. And my targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion is 28, my android device API is android 28, my emulator API is 23

and the logcat as following:

```
2019-03-15 09:11:49.867 26152-26152/com.uitest W/com.uitest: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-03-15 09:11:49.873 26152-26152/com.uitest I/chatty: uid=10049(com.uitest) identical 10 lines
2019-03-15 09:11:49.873 26152-26152/com.uitest W/com.uitest: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-03-15 09:11:49.915 26152-26152/com.uitest I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-03-15 09:11:50.088 26152-26152/com.uitest D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-03-15 09:11:50.168 26152-26170/com.uitest I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-03-15 09:11:50.168 26152-26170/com.uitest I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-03-15 09:11:50.169 26152-26170/com.uitest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-03-15 09:11:50.169 26152-26170/com.uitest D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2019-03-15 09:11:50.184 26152-26170/com.uitest D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2019-03-15 09:11:54.270 26152-26152/com.uitest W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@2732a9
2019-03-15 09:11:54.477 26152-26170/com.uitest D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2019-03-15 09:11:54.521 26152-26152/com.uitest W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://vfx.mtime.cn/Video/2019/02/08/mp4/190208204943376259.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://vfx.mtime.cn/Video/2019/02/08/mp4/190208204943376259.mp4
2019-03-15 09:11:54.521 26152-26152/com.uitest V/MediaHTTPService: MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@f158d8c): Cookies: null
2019-03-15 09:11:54.578 26152-26165/com.uitest V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection: CookieManager created: java.net.CookieManager@b0e0224
2019-03-15 09:11:54.580 26152-26165/com.uitest V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@f158d8c): cookieHandler: java.net.CookieManager@b0e0224 Cookies: null
2019-03-15 09:11:54.594 26152-26165/com.uitest D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-03-15 09:11:55.136 26152-26170/com.uitest W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x95077008 disconnect failed
2019-03-15 09:12:24.841 26152-26166/com.uitest E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
2019-03-15 09:12:24.842 26152-26152/com.uitest E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
2019-03-15 09:12:24.842 26152-26152/com.uitest D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648
2019-03-15 09:12:25.037 26152-26170/com.uitest D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
```

Answer (score 1):

I could fix this problem by adding this to my manifest android:usesCleartextTraffic="true":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

For further information pls check this answear https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/3433232

Answer (score 0):

Remove all and just use

```
 videoView.setVideoPath(videoUrl);

        videoView.start();
```

Comment: it will take some time for buffering

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 mVideoViewIntro = findViewById(R.id.video_view_intro);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoViewIntro);
    mVideoViewIntro.setMediaController(mediaController);
    mVideoViewIntro.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("YOURURLGOESHERE"));
    mVideoViewIntro.start();
    mImageViewClose.setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());

    mVideoViewIntro.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener((mp1, arg1, arg2) -> {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mp1.start();
        });
    });
```